# Angular.js converting my .html urls to just /something removing .html

Tags: angularjs

I want to convert my angular pages,  I am using `ng-includes` but my pages has .html extensions, I would like have just **/mypage**

sample:

www.mypage.com/projects.html

**I want archive this:**

www.mypage.com/projects

**html**

```
<!-- header -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">logo</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- header -->

<div>
<div ng-include="'app/pages/projects.html'"></div>
</div>


<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container text-center">
footer
  </div>
</footer>
```

**js:**

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);

App.controller('ProjectCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('app/projects.json')
       .then(function(res){
          $scope.projects = res.data;
        });
});



 .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $routeProvider
            .when('/projects', {
                templateUrl : 'projects.html',
                controller : mainController
            });

        // use the HTML5 History API
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
```

js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3ww49zq7/

how can make it?

thanks.

Comment: What is stopping you converting the links?

Comment: when I try : localhost:9000/projects , I dont get the page, I need open:  localhost:9000/projects.html  to see my page :(

Comment: did you configure server for html5mode?

Comment: no ideia :(, I runing with grunt serve

Comment: Then I suggest you read up on how `html5mode` works and the server side implications

Comment: Not sure if I can post this as an answer, so I comment. Can you replace `<a href="projects.html">` by `<a href="#/projects">` in your link? I guess the **#** is important in URLs :)

Answer (score 1):

**At the first** you will need to use ngRoute and declare it as a dependency in your module

```
var App = angular.module('App', ['ngRoute']);
```

Then you can use routeProvider

**Second :**
You should use the `ng-view` directive to tell the angular that this div will be used to load the views.

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

**Third :**

You should change your links to the same in the routeprovieder

```
 <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
```

should be

```
 <li class="active"><a href="/index">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="/projects">Projects</a></li>
```

and you should make sure that these links match the case in the routeProvider Object.

You should declare the controller you are using in the routeProvider
here is a plunker to demonstrate :.http://plnkr.co/edit/DrPG9WtLg8abpLQpVj0W?p=preview

Comment: thanks that is really what I looking for, but just a problem: when I click in the links appear: http://localhost:8000/projects.html#/page3 , I would like be just like that: http://localhost:8000/#/page3 , whithout the .html , understand?

Comment: Just add a case in the route provider like '.when("/".{ ... ' .. This is will be the default to load when there is no routes in the link. Then start the server like this localhost:8000/ without any routes . It will work.

Comment: did not work :(, can you update your question? please?